# Why does my datetime have trouble with the 31st?

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following piece of code on a site I'm working on. It was written by a previous developer, so I am unsure of exactly how to deal with it:

```
$datetime = new DateTime("$dt_start_ymd +$gap month");
$dt_next = new DateTime("Thursday " . $datetime->format('Y-m-01'));
$dt_next_0 = $dt_next->setTime(02, 00)->getTimestamp();
$dt_next = $dt_next->getTimestamp();
```

The variable `$gap` is an incrementing count (1, 2, 3, etc). The code above should output a sequence of dates listing the first thursday for each month for a number of months as indicated by `$gap`

i.e. 05/07/2017, 03/08/2017, 07/09/2017 (those being the first Thursday of those respective months).

The code works fine on most dates, but for a reason I cannot fathom if it is passed a date that is the 31st of a month (i.e. 2017-05-31) the system breaks and outputs incorrect answers.

Comment: Why is it Y-m-01 and not Y-m-d or Y-m-j

Comment: @clearshot66 because he's fetching the *first* Thursday of each month.

Comment: Got it, was looking at that the wrong way

Comment: I suspect the issue is that, for the 31st of May, this: `new DateTime("2017-05-31 +1 month")` becomes the 1st of July as there are only 30 days in June not 31. If you can change `$dt_start_ymd` so that's it's **not** `Y-m-d` format but instead `Y-m-01` (like it is where you `->format()` it) you *should* be OK.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you don't just use something like `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first Thursday of May 2017'));`, replacing the month and year in a loop as required?

Comment: ^ that would work even better :) Relative date formats work with `DateTime` too.

Comment: @HerrPink I didn't write this code, someone else did. I'm trying to understand why they did.

Comment: @evilscary Ah okay. I think my suggestion might be easier for future developers to understand, so if you're in a position to refactor this code then you might want to take the opportunity!

Comment: @evilscary, why does it matter? "someone else" wrote buggy code and you've been given a better solution.

Comment: @HerrPink could you add your solution as an answer and maybe factor in the dynamic elements? Then I can give you an accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code is unnecessarily complicated. In addition, you're in a situation where if the given date is the 31st and you attempt to add 1 month, you're ending up in a situation where it's attempting to find the 31st of the next month, which does not exist except in December->January.

You might want to consider something like

```
$currentDate = new \DateTime();

$iterations = 10;

for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
    $first_thursday = new \DateTime(
        sprintf('first Thursday of %s', $currentDate->format('F Y'))
    );

    $nextDate = new \DateTime($currentDate->format('Y-m-d'));
    $nextDate->add(new \DateInterval('P1M'));

    if ($nextDate->format('m') > $currentDate->format('m') + 1) {
        $nextDate->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    }

    $currentDate = $nextDate;

    echo $first_thursday->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

This will give you the first Thursday in every month for the next 10 months, and I think is much easier to read than the example you gave.

EDIT: I've updated the code so that it doesn't skip out months. See my comment below.

Comment: Hang on. I made a mistake. This will skip months out sometimes if it runs on the 31st. Let me make a change and I'll edit.

Comment: I've fixed that mistake. Sorry about that. I'm now checking to ensure that the result of adding P1M is in fact the next month. If it's not, it subtracts one day to make sure that it is, e.g.: Adding P1M to 2017-05-31 results in 2017-07-01. Subtracting P1D gives 2017-06-30, which is the year and month we want.

Comment: You could have also cheated a bit at the start to avoid the issue with the 31st skipping months by doing:`$currentDate = new \DateTime("first day of this month");`